# Add a class on dynamic element

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I use a countdown DIV that adds a class 'timeisover' to itself when it reaches 00:00:00 and I just want to add a class to his parent when it happens.

```
<div class="parent-countdown">
    <div class="countdown">
        <!-- countdown elements here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$('.countdown').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('timeisover') {
        $('.parent-countdown').addClass('disable-countdown');
    )
});
```

So I guess I need an "event listener" which works live and checks permanently if the element receives this class? I usually use `.on` with `click` event but for this, I'm not sure how to proceed :/ So any help would be much appreciate :)

Comment: What countdown library are you using? You need to listen for the event that raises when the countdown ends and then call `addClass()`

Comment: It's on WordPress and I'm using a plugin called HurryTimer. I'm actually digging into the JS code to understand how this class is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HurryTimer documentation](https://docs.hurrytimer.com/developer-documentation) says it has a `"hurryt:finished"` EventName:

> **hurryt:finished**: *Fires after timer has reached zero.*

```js
$('.countdown').on('hurryt:finished', function(event, campaign){

  $(this).closest('.parent-countdown').addClass('disable-countdown');

});
```

Comment: I saw this while digging through the source code, and I wasn't (too) far from the solution, but you saved me some precious time. Thanks a lot :)  I didn't think to look in the documentation. Damn :p

Comment: @dragoweb yes, docs can be daunting, specially for badly written ones. This one on the other hand seemed helpful ;)